# How to use 2 columns in one function(t.test) after group by

Tags: r, aggregate, t-test

I have a list where I need to use `t.test` function over 2 columns. I know I can just do

```
t.test(myF$before, myF$after)
```

but after grouping I have many groups and it would be a hassle to do all one by one.

I get my data with SQL Query such as below:

```
myF <- sqlQuery(conn, 'Select colA, colB, colC, before, after from MyTable')
```

following code will give me mean over `before` and `after` columns one by one

```
aggregate(cbind(before = before, after = after) ~ colA+colB+colC, 
          data = myF, 
          FUN = mean)
```

Output is similar to this:

```
colA      colB     colC      before after
GroupA1   GroupB1  GroupC1   110    11
GroupA2   GroupB1  GroupC1   44     15
GroupA3 .....................
......
```

So I want to get `t.test` results between `before` and `after` columns for each group. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a clear input or expected output, but it looks like, e.g.,

```
myF %>% group_by(colA, colB, colC) %>% summarise(pval = t.test(.$before, .$after)$p.val)
```

should achieve what you want.

Comment: @sertsedat, I'm not sure where this error is coming from, you should need only `library(tidyverse)` other than that line.